# cgminer doesnt use my GPU

Tags: miner-configuration, cgminer, linux, gpu

CentOS6 x64, build last cgminer with openCL support

```
[ay@pandora6 log]$ sudo lshw | grep -i geforce
             product: G73 [GeForce 7600 GS]

[ay@pandora6 log]$ uname -a
Linux pandora6 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 13 00:26:49 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[ay@pandora6 log]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

[ay@pandora6 /]$ nvidia-settings -v
nvidia-settings:  version 304.108  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-06)  Wed Jul 31 20:47:31 PDT 2013
```

Why **cgminer** does not use GPU ?

```
[ay@pandora6 /]$ /usr/local/bin/cgminer -n
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] CL Platform 0 vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] CL Platform 0 name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] CL Platform 0 version: OpenCL 1.1 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 (684.213)
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] Error -1: Getting Device IDs (num)
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] clDevicesNum returned error, no GPUs usable
 [2013-10-11 14:58:09] 0 GPU devices max detected
```

Comment: Mining on a 7 year old, low end nVidia card is just *not* sensible. I don't even think it's possible on 7xxx cards. I have an ASIC miner that's 40 times more power efficient than your GPU would be, and it can't pay for the power it takes to run it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz does the sensibility of the mining operation depend on what you are trying to achieve?  For example if you wanted to contribute to the "security" of the bitcoin network is any sort of mining helpful or not?

Comment: @Deesbek Not likely. If you mine in a pool, you aren't really contributing to the security of the network much. And if you solo mine, you won't have any effect unless you find a block, which you likely never will.